# Can't start Activity from Recycler Adapter

Tags: android, android-activity, android-recyclerview

I tried to find solution, but my weak programming skills didn't help me to solve problem.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class GridAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GridAdapter.ViewHolder> {
List<HeroItem> mItems;
Context mContext;
MyOnItemClickListener listener;

public GridAdapter(Context context) {
    super();
    this.mContext = context;
    mItems = new ArrayList<HeroItem>();
    HeroItem species = new HeroItem();
    //species.setName("Amur Leopard");
    species.setThumbnail(R.drawable.test1);
    mItems.add(species);


    species = new HeroItem();
    //species.setName("Black Rhino");
    species.setThumbnail(R.drawable.test2);
    mItems.add(species);

    species = new HeroItem();
    //species.setName("Orangutan");
    species.setThumbnail(R.drawable.test3);
    mItems.add(species);

    species = new HeroItem();
    //species.setName("Sea Lions");
    species.setThumbnail(R.drawable.test4);
    mItems.add(species);

    species = new HeroItem();
    //species.setName("Indian Elephant");
    species.setThumbnail(R.drawable.test5);
    mItems.add(species);

    species = new HeroItem();
    // species.setName("Giant Panda");
    species.setThumbnail(R.drawable.test6);
    mItems.add(species);

    species = new HeroItem();
    //species.setName("Snow Leopard");
    species.setThumbnail(R.drawable.test1);
    mItems.add(species);

    species = new HeroItem();
    //species.setName("Dolphin");
    species.setThumbnail(R.drawable.test1);
    mItems.add(species);
}
@Override
public GridAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, final int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.grid_item, viewGroup, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
    HeroItem nature = mItems.get(position);
    //viewHolder.tvspecies.setText(nature.getName());
    //viewHolder.imgThumbnail.setImageResource(nature.getThumbnail());
    Picasso.with(mContext)
            .load(nature.getThumbnail())
            .into(viewHolder.imgThumbnail);
    viewHolder.setListener(new MyOnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void MyOnClickListener(int position) {
            //Log.d("Click","Position: " + position);
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, Wolverine.class);
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mItems.size();
}


class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    public ImageView imgThumbnail;
    //public TextView tvspecies;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imgThumbnail = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.photoView);
        //tvspecies = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_species);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        listener.MyOnClickListener(getAdapterPosition());
    }

    public void setListener(MyOnItemClickListener onItemClick) {
        listener = onItemClick;
    }
}

public interface MyOnItemClickListener {
    void MyOnClickListener(int position);
}
}
```

So, I wrote my own `listener` that needs `position` of the `item`, as you can  see. I have no  problems with  showing `position` in logs `Log.d("Click","Position: " + position);` , but I still can't  to  start  new Activity.

And here is code of my `fragment Activity` that uses  `adapter`

```
  import android.graphics.Point;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
  import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
  import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
  import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
  import android.view.Display;
  import android.view.LayoutInflater;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.ViewGroup;
  import android.view.WindowManager;

  public class TabHero extends Fragment {
RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
int widthRecycler,widthScreen,padding;

public static TabHero newInstance() {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    TabHero fragment = new TabHero();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_hero, container, false);
    // Calling the RecyclerView
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    // The number of Columns
    mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    mAdapter = new GridAdapter(getContext());
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    return v;

}
```

}

What I do wrong?

Comment: as per your code on first position you want to start activity right?  for more info did u registered Wolverine activity in manifest

Comment: @Pavan , omg! That was the only problem! Spasibo!

Answer (score 0):

```
itemViewHolder.CategoryItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i=new Intent(context, SubcatogaryActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("id",Integer.toString(received_dataList.get(position).getId()));

                context.startActivity(i);
            }
        });
```

Comment: position is the current item position in Recycler View.